# I am new to python. I am having the following code.**No inheritance concept**. I guess composition helps

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, composition

I have the below code. I need to call as bt.BT_ON only. I don't want to use inheritance concept.Is there any way that I can achieve it?

```
from __future__ import print_function
class tool(object):
    def BT_ON(self):
        print("BT on")
    def WIFI_ON(self):
        print("WIFI on")
class BTMGR(object):
    def __init__(self):
       self.tl = tool()

 bt=BTMGR()
 bt.BT_ON()
```

I tried doing following,

```
class tool(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        print(parent)
        self.parent=parent
    def BT_ON(self):
        print("BT on")
    def WIFI_ON(self):
        print("WIFI on")
 class BTMGR(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tl = tool(self)
 class WIFIMGR(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tool = tool()

bt=BTMGR()
bt.BT_ON()
```

But it didnt work. I dont know exactly what to put at "parent".

I want to use the methods of tool from the instance of BTMGR itself. No duplicating of methods in BTMGR.

Comment: Please provide a more meaningful title!

Comment: Please also clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks.hope now it clarifies

Comment: No, it does not. Please clarify what you are trying to attempt, what you have tried and why that didn’t work.

Comment: @Jamie it works that way. But I cant use like that. I have to somehow make tool methods a part of BTMGR class i guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the methods of the class `tool` directly from your `BTMGR` class, then you have no choice but duplicate their definitions:

```
class BTMGR(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tl = tool(self)
    def BT_ON(self):
        self.tl.BT_ON()

class WIFIMGR(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tool = tool()
    def WIFI_ON(self):
        self.tool.WIFI_ON()

bt = BTMGR()
bt.BT_ON()

wf = WIFIMGR()
wf.WIFI_ON()
```

Comment: duplicating is not good and not optimized  right?

Comment: You are not really duplicating it, you are delegating the implementation to your `tool`, so that’s good. You are only duplicating the public interface, providing a loose coupling to the underlying implementation (that is a good thing).

Comment: This is also not accepted as per the situation. Could be please tell me if there is any other way?

Comment: There isn’t. Magic code deduplication is not a thing.